# Do we want hats - 2013 edition

Tags: discussion, hats

[Last year, Security.SE took part in the Winter Bash Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges):

[image]

Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

Here's the run down of last year's:

- The event ran from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013.
- Users had their entire hat collection on http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com.
- Individual users who didn’t want to participate, didn’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat had an "I hate hats" option available..
- The only visual change to the site itself was the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

We need to let Stack Exchange know by end of November 2013, so **vote on one of the two answers below**.

Comment: But wait! I'm from Australia and we are in the middle of a heatwave and the only hat I'll wear is a [cork hat!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cork_hat)

Comment: Cork hat may be an option...I'll take this as a yes :-)

Comment: and t-shirts. I want t-shirts!

Comment: So - the numbers already give me a positive indication. We're opted in now. If you really don't want hats, the I hate hats link hides it all from you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes! Gimme dem hats! I want all sorts of winter themed nonsense!

Comment: How could we not want hats? Hats are the cure for @AviD's shiny pate!

Comment: "Cure"?? Shiny pates ARE the cure for hats!

Comment: I bet I would start making sense with one of these hats on!

Comment: @Simon Not very likely.

Comment: Of course we want hats!

Comment: [FREE HAT!](http://www.southparkstudios.com/clips/153543/different-hat) Never under-estimate the power of a free hat.

Answer (score 0):

No - please, not more insanity! I want this site to be all about Security!

Comment: Boo.  Want moar hats!!